# Confidence intervals from mocel coefficients vs whole model

Tags: r, lm, predict, confidence-interval

I'm trying to demonstrate that there is an important difference between two ways of making linear model predictions. The first way, which my heart tells me is more correct, uses `predict.lm` which as I understand preserves the correlations between coefficients. The second approach tries to use the parameters independently.

Is this the correct way to show the difference? The two approaches seem somewhat close.

Also, is the StdErr of the coefficients the same as the standard deviation of their distributions? Or have I misunderstood what the model table is saying.

Below is a quick reprex to show what I mean:

```r
# fake dataset
xs <- runif(200, min = -1, max = 1)
true_inter <- -1.3
true_slope <- 3.1
ybar <- true_inter + true_slope*xs
ys <- rnorm(200, ybar, sd = 1)


model <- lm(ys~xs)

# predictions

coef_sterr <- summary(model)$coefficients
inters <- rnorm(500, mean = coef_sterr[1,1], sd = coef_sterr[1,2])
slopes <- rnorm(500, mean = coef_sterr[2,1], sd = coef_sterr[2,2])

newx <- seq(from = -1, to= 1, length.out = 20)
avg_predictions <- cbind(1, newx) %*% rbind(inters, slopes)

conf_predictions <- apply(avg_predictions, 1, quantile, probs = c(.25, .975), simplify = TRUE)

# from confint
conf_interval <- predict(model, newdata=data.frame(xs = newx),
                         interval="confidence",
                         level = 0.95)

# plot to visualize
plot(ys~xs)


# averages are exactly the same
abline(model)
abline(a = coef(model)[1], b = coef(model)[2], col = "red")

# from predict, using parameter covariance
matlines(newx, conf_interval[,2:3], col = "blue", lty=1, lwd = 3)
# from simulated lines, ignoring parameter covariance
matlines(newx, t(conf_predictions), col = "orange", lty = 1, lwd = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I might use `MASS::mvrnorm(coef(model), vcov(model))` vs `MASS::mvrnorm(n=100, coef(model), diag(diag(vcov(model))))` to get resampled parameters from models with and without the covariance.  Your covariance is almost zero in the example so the results will be similar.

Comment: If you want a higher covariance between intercept and slope, try using only positive x for your fake data, that is `xs <- runif(200, min = 0, max = 1)`.  Also there is a mistake in your code, should read `probs = c(.025, .975)` not `probs = c(.25, .975)`

Answer (score 0):

In this case, they would be close because there is very little correlation between the model parameters, so drawing them from two independent normals versus a multivariate normal is not that different:

```r
set.seed(519)
xs <- runif(200, min = -1, max = 1)
true_inter <- -1.3
true_slope <- 3.1
ybar <- true_inter + true_slope*xs
ys <- rnorm(200, ybar, sd = 1)


model <- lm(ys~xs)
cov2cor(vcov(model))
#             (Intercept)          xs
# (Intercept)  1.00000000 -0.08054106
# xs          -0.08054106  1.00000000
```

Also, it is probably worth calculating both of the intervals the same way, though it shouldn't make that much difference.  That said, 500 observations may not be enough to get reliable estimates of the 2.5th and 97.5th percentiles of the distribution.  Let's consider a slightly more complex example.  Here, the two X variables are correlated - the correlation of the parameters derives in part from the correlation of the columns of the design matrix, X.

```r
set.seed(519)
X <- MASS::mvrnorm(200, c(0,0), matrix(c(1,.65,.65,1), ncol=2))
b <- c(-1.3, 3.1, 2.5)
ytrue <- cbind(1,X) %*% b
y <- ytrue + rnorm(200, 0, .5*sd(ytrue))
dat <- data.frame(y=y, x1=X[,1], x2=X[,2])


model <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data=dat)
cov2cor(vcov(model))
#             (Intercept)          x1          x2
# (Intercept)  1.00000000  0.02417386 -0.01515887
# x1           0.02417386  1.00000000 -0.73228003
# x2          -0.01515887 -0.73228003  1.00000000
```

In this example, the coefficients for `x1` and `x2` are correlated around -0.73. As you'll see, this still doesn't result in a huge difference.  Let's calculate the relevant statistics.

First, we draw `B1` using the multivariate method that you rightly suspect is correct.  Then, we'll draw `B2` from a bunch of independent normals (actually, I'm using a multivariate normal with a diagonal variance-covariance matrix, which is the same thing).

```r
b_est <- coef(model)
v <- vcov(model)
B1 <- MASS::mvrnorm(2500, b_est, v, empirical=TRUE)
B2 <- MASS::mvrnorm(2500, b_est, diag(diag(v)), empirical = TRUE)
```

Now, let's make a hypothetical X matrix and generate the relevant predictions:

```r
hypX <- data.frame(x1=seq(-3,3, length=50), 
                     x2 = mean(dat$x2))

yhat1 <- as.matrix(cbind(1, hypX)) %*% t(B1)
yhat2 <- as.matrix(cbind(1, hypX)) %*% t(B2)
```

Then we can calculate confidence intervals, etc...

```r
yh1_ci <- t(apply(yhat1, 1, function(x)unname(quantile(x, c(.025,.975)))))
yh2_ci <- t(apply(yhat2, 1, function(x)unname(quantile(x, c(.025,.975)))))
yh1_ci <- as.data.frame(yh1_ci)
yh2_ci <- as.data.frame(yh2_ci)
names(yh1_ci) <- names(yh2_ci) <- c("lwr", "upr")
yh1_ci$fit <- c(as.matrix(cbind(1, hypX)) %*% b_est)
yh2_ci$fit <- c(as.matrix(cbind(1, hypX)) %*% b_est)
yh1_ci$method <- factor(1, c(1,2), labels=c("Multivariate", "Independent"))
yh2_ci$method <- factor(2, c(1,2), labels=c("Multivariate", "Independent"))
yh1_ci$x1 <- hypX[,1]
yh2_ci$x1 <- hypX[,1]
yh <- rbind(yh1_ci, yh2_ci)
```

We could then plot the two confidence intervals as you did.

```r
ggplot(yh, aes(x=x1, y=fit, ymin=lwr, ymax=upr, fill=method)) + 
  geom_ribbon(colour="transparent", alpha=.25) + 
  geom_line() + 
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Perhaps a better visual would be to compare the widths of the intervals.

```r
w1 <- yh1_ci$upr - yh1_ci$lwr
w2 <- yh2_ci$upr - yh2_ci$lwr
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(x=hypX[,1], y=w2-w1)) + 
  theme_classic() + 
  labs(x="x1", y="Width (Independent) - Width (Multivariate)")
```

[image]

This shows that for small values of `x1`, the independent confidence intervals are wider than the multivariate ones.  For values of `x1` above 0, it's a more mixed bag.

This tells you that there is some difference, but you don't need the simulation to know which one is 'right'.  That's because the prediction is a linear combination of constants and random variables.

[image]

In this case, the `b` terms are the random variables and the `x` values are the constants.  We know that the variance of a linear combination can be calculated this way:

[image]

All that is to say that your intuition is correct.